# laravel query to compare two string from DB

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I used laravel's query builder.

```
$email=DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->select('e_mail')->get();
dd($email);
```

and, this is result.

```
Collection {#231 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#229 ▼
      +"e_mail": "admin@test.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

but test code's result was False.

```
$email=DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->select('e_mail')->get();
"admin@test.net"!=$email[0]
```

I found other questions, but didn't find solution.
please your advise. thanks.

Comment: use ->first(); instead of ->get();  and compare $email['e_mail'] != "admin@test.net" /// or if you use get() you need to use $email[0]['e_mail'] != "admin@test.net"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output, it seems instead of `$email[0]`, you need to use `$email[0]['e_mail']`, if it's an array, or you need to use `$email[0]->e_mail`, if it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

Please use it like this:

```
$email=DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->select('e_mail')->get();

"admin@test.net"!=$email[0]->e_mail
```

Answer (score 0):

you are finding using id.. so i assume it is unique.. if using `get()` it will return as array.

use Eloquent..

```
$user = Users::select('e_mail')->find(1);
// $user = Users::select('e_mail')->where('id', 1)->first(); //this also can

if("admin@test.net" != $user->email) 
{
    //
}
```

or Query..use first();

```
$user=DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->select('e_mail')->first(); 

if("admin@test.net" != $user->e_mail) 
{
    //
}
```